# How to use DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using below code to calculate score, on list of question answer by user, but getting error sequence contains no matching element.

Now here I am trying to select first selected option of question and doing sum of score of that option. But when there is no option selected it says no matching element found hence I added `DefaultIfEmpty` but it still throws same error.

Now If I use `FirstOrDefault`, I am getting null values, then I have to add null check in Sum, which doesn't look appropriate. Should I provide my default in `FirstOrDefault` is that solution?

```
int Score = Questions.Select(x => x.Options.First(o => o.IsSelected))
                     .DefaultIfEmpty()
                     .Sum(s => s == null ? 0 : s.Score);
```

So what is best way to write this linq query.

Comment: "As per documentation `DefaultIfEmpty` should return empty list" where does it say this? It clearly says "Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the type parameter's default value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.". The _type parameter's default value_ is not an empty list.

Comment: Is `Options` a `List<Option>` inside a `Question`? If so do you initiate that List in the constructor or somewhere inside `Question`? If you could provide that portion of your code as well it might be easier to figure out a solution for you problem.

Comment: @IDarkCoder you are right I interpreted wrongly I think, I will edit question.

Comment: @MirkoBrandt yes Option list is inside question and get initialized within question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your code is written, you're calling `DefaultIfEmpty` on the set of options for all questions, thus it will have no effect as long as the set of questions is not empty. And given that a question with no selected options exists, as you have pointed out, the inner call to `First` will throw.

If you want to use `DefaultIfEmpty`, you could do it on the options collection as follows:

```
int Score = Questions.Select(x => x.Options
                                     .Where(o => o.IsSelected)
                                     .Select(o => o.Score)
                                     .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     .First()
                      )
                 .Sum();
```

Here, since you project to an integer collection before calling `DefaultIfEmpty`, it will yield a singleton collection with 0 in it in the empty case, as 0 is the default value for `int`. However, `FirstOrDefault` will achieve the same thing as the calls to `DefaultIfEmpty().First()` in this case.

Comment: This looks good. As you already suggested I'd go with `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `DefaultIfEmpty().First()` as it looks cleaner that way.

Comment: @Jonas Høgh You are right I was applying DefaultIfEmpty on wrong collection. This make sense and worked like charm.